# ¿Como saber si una variable contiene una fecha?

Tags: laravel, date, carbon

Hola estoy construyendo tablas dinamicamente. Por lo que para saber el tipo de dato que voy a guardar en x campo. Tengo que discriminar los datos.

Ejemplo tengo esto.

```
if(is_int($x))
{
   // es entero
}

if(is_bool($x))
{
   // es un boleano
}

if(is_float($x))
{
    // Es un numero flotante
}
```

Esta es un poco dudosa.

```
if(is_string($x))
{
    // es un string
}
```

El problema es con las fechas.

Tengo el siguiente formato de fechas.

> 2019-21-06 00:00:00

Estoy utilizando Carbon y laravel. No si haya una forma directa de probar la fecha. Y siendo así me podrían decir el método o la función con la que puedo validar el formato de dicha fecha.

Se me ocurre algo asi.

```
if(preg_match('^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$', $x)){
   // es una fecha
}
```

Comment: estas haciendo eso para validar los datos de entrada antes de guardarlo en la base de datos?

Comment: Cómo es eso de **construir tablas dinamicamente**? Por qué necesitas hacer eso y no simplemente definir tus modelos y controladores?

Comment: De una base de datos que tengo en AWS cuando respaldo las tablas a una base de datos local. Esta tabla podría existir o no existir. Si no existe la creo, solo que para crear la tabla tengo que saber que tipo de dato voy a respaldar.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar [`Carbon::createFromFormat`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats) así:

```
$dt = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $x);
if ($dt !== false) {
    // $x es una cadena que cumple el formato
}
```

Comment: Excelente. Gracias por tu respuesta.